# Can't recongnize my SSD device file in /dev

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, dev

I am using Ubuntu and can't find my SSD device file. The /dev directory has following contents:

```
agpgart
audio
audio1
audio2
audio3
audioctl
char
console
core
dsp
dsp1
dsp2
dsp3
fd
full
kmem
kmsg
log
loop0
loop1
loop2
loop3
loop4
loop5
loop6
loop7
mem
midi0
midi00
midi01
midi02
midi03
midi1
midi2
midi3
mixer
mixer1
mixer2
mixer3
mpu401data
mpu401stat
null
port
ptmx
pts
ptyp0
ptyp1
ptyp2
ptyp3
ptyp4
ptyp5
ptyp6
ptyp7
ptyp8
ptyp9
ptypa
ptypb
ptypc
ptypd
ptype
ptypf
ram
ram0
ram1
ram10
ram11
ram12
ram13
ram14
ram15
ram16
ram2
ram3
ram4
ram5
ram6
ram7
ram8
ram9
random
rmidi0
rmidi1
rmidi2
rmidi3
sequencer
shm
smpte0
smpte1
smpte2
smpte3
sndstat
stderr
stdin
stdout
tty
tty0
tty1
tty10
tty11
tty12
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
ttyp0
ttyp1
ttyp2
ttyp3
ttyp4
ttyp5
ttyp6
ttyp7
ttyp8
ttyp9
ttypa
ttypb
ttypc
ttypd
ttype
ttypf
urandom
xconsole
zero
```

Can some one suggest which should represent my SSD file?

Edit: mount command gives following output:

```
/dev/simfs / simfs rw,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=943720k,mode=755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
```

Edit 2: Contents of /etc/fstab are:

```
proc  /proc       proc    defaults    0    0
none  /dev/pts    devpts  rw,gid=5,mode=620    0    0
none  /run/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them.

`/dev/simfs` indicates that your Ubuntu is running on a "simfs" device, which is a virtual OpenVZ filesystem. The entire "server" is just an OpenVZ container on the host hardware – probably alongside several dozen more containers belonging to other customers – and does not have access to the actual filesystem structure, much less the hardware.

So it can only access a small part of the real disk, through the `simfs` device.

Comment: But /dev/simfs doesn't exist. Why? And is it possible to partition it? :)

Comment: @Ashish: Because it's not a _real_ device, it's emulated by OpenVZ just to have something to show in the mtab instead of leaking information about devices on the host. And no, you cannot partition it, because there's no such thing as partitions in this case. You don't have a VPS with disks and such. You have a container, running from a _subdirectory_ on the host.